# Chained dispatch based on result from onAuthStateChange runs forever without apparent reason

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, dispatch

Im trying to update my redux state value based on onAuthStateChanged. When the user value changes i want my redux store to reflect that. The onAuthStateChanged triggers a dispatch that sets the userAuth object in the store to be the logged in person. Afterwards I want to fetch all the data that is relevant to the logged in user. But when I use the authObject that I return from the dispatch to call antorher dispatch it start to fire forever.

This is how my useEffect hook is set up. The currentUserAuth and the currentUser dont interact at all and both are memoized which is why I dont understand why it refires.

```
   useEffect(() => {
      const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChangedListener((user) => {
         dispatch(setCurrentUserAuth(user)).unwrap()
            .then(user => {
                  // dispatch(setCurrentUser(user));
            });
      });

      return unsubscribe;
   });
```

However, if I call it like this it works

```
useEffect(() => {
      const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChangedListener((user) => {
         dispatch(setCurrentUserAuth(user))
      });

      return unsubscribe;
   });

   useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(setCurrentUser(currentUserAuth))
   }, [currentUserAuth]);
```

and I cant figure out why. I would really like for the above code to be the one that works because I have more chains incomming based on the return value of the first dispatch.

Comment: In your first one, you have no dependency list, so it fires on every render. Looks like it should have an empty dependency list.

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much. The problem drove me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

In your first one, you have no dependency list, so it fires on every render. It should have an empty dependency list so it only fires once.